# Using SSIS Package Configuration to change flat file path?

Tags: ssis

I want to use the SSIS Package Configuration to change the path of several flat file destinations, but only the path, not the filename.  Basically I have alot of flat files going to the same directory, but each has it's own name.  Unfortunately the property on the flat file object includes both the filename and directory as one string.  I would like to set it up so it is easy to change the directory for all of these, but where they still have their own unique filename.

Any ideas?  Can this be done somehow with expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, can be done with Expressions.

- Define a package variable for Path
- Define an expression for ConnectionString with `@[User:Path] + "\filename"`
- Use a package config to define the variable (or on command line)

I don't have SSIS on this PC so no screenies, sorry. Check [this](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1084) and [this](http://www.ssistalk.com/how-tos/using-sql-server-configurations-to-configure-flat-file-connection-manager/) though